# Userform on excel worksheet dissappears when excel sheet has activeX controls! Why

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to this forum.  Please bear with me.
I have been working on a project in which I plan to have a worksheet that contains a userform and some activeX controls.  The activeX controls are on the worksheet.  I have duplicated the problem I'm facing with the script below.  When subroutine finishes, the userform is not visible on the screen.  If I comment-out the lines pertaining to the OLEObject, then I can see the userform as modeless on the screen.  The question is, is this behavior expected?  Why does the userform fail to be visible when there are activeX on the worksheet?

```
Sub DemoFailure()
Dim myOleObj As OLEObject
Dim myRng As Range

Set myRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C4")
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Select
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
With ActiveSheet
    myRng.RowHeight = 20
    Set myOleObj = .OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CheckBox.1",  DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=myRng.Left + 2, Top:=myRng.Top + 2,  Width:=myRng.Width - 4, Height:=myRng.Height - 4)
    With myOleObj
        '.Object.Caption =
        .Name = "CheckBox" & CStr(ii)
    End With
End With
UserForm1.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me (assuming "UserForm1" exists in the same module). This is a very rough recreation of your code, because I don't know from your question exactly what you are trying to achieve other than to get the box and Form to display at the same time:

```
Sub Macro2()

Dim myOleObj As OLEObject
Dim myRng As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet

Set myRng = ws.Range("C4")
myRng.RowHeight = 20

ws.OLEObjects.Add "Forms.CheckBox.1", _
    Left:=myRng.Left + 2, _
    Top:=myRng.Top + 2, _
    Width:=myRng.Width - 4, _
    Height:=myRng.Height - 1 _

Set myOleObj = ws.OLEObjects(1)

With myOleObj
    '.Object.Caption =
    .Name = "CheckBox" & CStr(ii)
End With

UserForm1.Show vmModeless

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Davy C,  your reply which included  (assuming "UserForm1" exists in the same module) was the answer to my problem.

Comment: Davy, my acceptance seems to be flawed.  I'm not sure if I used vbModeless in the UserForm1.Show when I tried out your suggestion. I initialized a new object of my UserForm in the module in which I had my activeX.  I revisited my  project after a long break and found that vbModeless causes the form to disappear.  My intention was to have a UserForm with some controls interact with some ActiveX controls on a Worksheet.  Can you advise?

Comment: I'm still dead in the water.  Need help... not sure if this thread has gone cold. What do I do to get this question back on the mainstream so that the experts can give their suggestions