# Userform is not visible when placed on the same worksheet along with activeX controls

Tags: vba, excel

I have asked this question before found under this link 
[Userform on excel worksheet dissappears when excel sheet has activeX controls! Why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35970881/userform-on-excel-worksheet-dissappears-when-excel-sheet-has-activex-controls-w)
and I found that I had err'd in accepting the answer.  I'm trying to reopen the question again here.
I have been working on a project in which I plan to have a worksheet that contains a userform and some activeX controls. The activeX controls are on the worksheet. I have duplicated the problem I'm facing with the script below. When subroutine finishes, the userform is not visible on the screen. If I comment-out the lines pertaining to the OLEObject, then I can see the userform as modeless on the screen. The question is, is this behavior expected? Why does the userform fail to be visible when there are activeX on the worksheet?

```
Sub DemoFailure()
Dim myOleObj As OLEObject
Dim myRng As Range

Set myRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C4")
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Select
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
With ActiveSheet
    myRng.RowHeight = 20
    Set myOleObj = .OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CheckBox.1",     DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=myRng.Left + 2, Top:=myRng.Top + 2,   Width:=myRng.Width - 4, Height:=myRng.Height - 4)
    With myOleObj
        '.Object.Caption =
        .Name = "CheckBox" & CStr(ii)
    End With
End With
UserForm1.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding an ActiveX control to a worksheet causes a reset of the VBAproject when that routine ends, which is why your form gets unloaded. I suggest you either use Form controls rather than ActiveX, or use `OnTime` to show the form after the reset:

```
Sub DemoFailure()
Dim myOleObj As OLEObject
Dim myRng As Range

Set myRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C4")
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Select
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
With ActiveSheet
    myRng.RowHeight = 20
    Set myOleObj = .OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.CheckBox.1", DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=myRng.Left + 2, Top:=myRng.Top + 2, Width:=myRng.Width - 4, Height:=myRng.Height - 4)
    With myOleObj
        '.Object.Caption =
        .Name = "CheckBox" & CStr(ii)
    End With
End With
Application.OnTime Now(), "ShowIt"
End Sub
Sub ShowIt()
UserForm1.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```